# Filling an int array with bits in a bitset.

Tags: c++, arrays, int, fill, bitset

```
#define CHAR_BIT 8
union
{
     float input;   // assumes sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)
     int   output;
}    data;

data.input = 122.5;

bitset<sizeof(float) * CHAR_BIT>   bits(data.output);

int ieee[32];
for(int i = 0 ; i < 32 ; ++i){
    ieee[i] = (int)bits[i];
}
```

My intention is to fill the `ieee` array with the IEEE representation of a float, and is done (I've used code from another question), but there are 2 things  I don't understand:

1) Why do I have to use `#define CHAR_BIT 8` for a correct output?

2) How can I fill the `ieee` array with the correct bit values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Because you need to convert a size in bytes (that's what `sizeof(float)` is) to a size in bits (which is what `bitset` expects).

2) Looks to me like you are already putting the correct bit value into `ieee`. Can you give an example and say why you think it's wrong.

Comment: bitset is: 01000010111101010000000000000000 ieee is: 000000000000000010101111010000100

Comment: I tried your code, I get 000000000000000010101111010000100 for both. Maybe you made an error in the way you print it out.

Comment: the correct value(IEEE representation of 122.5) is in the bitset: 01000010111101010000000000000000 and I want that values in my array of int

Comment: The correct value depends on endianess considerations which are implementation defined.

Comment: Okay, I just want that ieee is equal to bitset (same numbers in the same order)

Comment: Well I get that if I write `ieee[i] = (int)bits[31-i]` instead of `ieee[i] = (int)bits[i]`.

Comment: `bitset<sizeof(float) * CHAR_BIT>   bits(data.output);` means that I reserve 32 bits and what I do then??

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. You do what you are already doing but with the change I posted in the comment above.

Comment: Is done, and works but data.output is empty :S how to construct an object with an empty value??

Comment: Sorry still not following you. Maybe you need to post a new question since this seems to be a new problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18664/discussion-between-freinn-and-john)